# pip looking to wrong directory after Anaconda installation

Tags: python, macos, pip, anaconda, compatibility

When I type 'pip' in terminal, I get the following error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5: 
bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I recently installed the Anaconda package for Mac using the standard installer on the website, which I think is what messed things up.

I had Python 3.6 installed through homebrew, as well as pip. I noticed that if my path includes `export PATH="//anaconda/bin:$PATH"`, then pip works fine. However when I remove this line from my bash profile (certain packages I work with have errors with anaconda's python), I get the error as above.

For some reason, pip is looking for Python 3.5, when I have 3.6 installed (for both anaconda and homebrew). Pip worked fine before installing anaconda. Note that pip is indeed in `/usr/local/bin/pip`.

Any ideas appreciated!